# Hide contents when page is scrolling down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a contents DIV which is positioned to fixed at bottom of the page.

It's HTML and CSS looks like this:

```
<div class="footer-fix">
    <p>This is its contents......</p>
</div>

.footer-fix {
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

My question is now I need to hide this fixed bar when page is scrolling down to the bottom or near the bottom of the page.

This is how I tried it in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var footer = $('.footer-fix');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) && footer.is(':visible')){
            footer.stop().fadeOut(300);
        }
        else if($(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height() - 100 && footer.is(':hidden')){
            footer.stop().fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
});
```

But this is not working for me. Can anybody tell what is the wrong with this.

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have it live? Could you provide us the link?

Comment: What is not working? What's the current behavior?

Comment: what are you getting .. any error?? describe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `(` , `)` around `($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100)` at `if` conditions

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var footer = $('.footer-fix');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) 
        && footer.is(':visible')) {
      footer.stop().fadeOut(300);
    } else if (($(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height() - 100) 
               && footer.is(':hidden')) {
      footer.stop().fadeIn(300);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 520px;
}
.footer-fix {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="footer-fix">
  <p>This is its contents......</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have `.stop()`

Also try changing `if, else if` to `if, else` and fix that syntax error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var footer = $('.footer-fix');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 100) && footer.is(':visible')){
            footer.fadeOut(300);
        }
        else {
            footer.fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
});
```