# Hide <div> tag once the client starts scrolling down via CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, hide, visibility

Is it possible to hide a div once the person starts scrolling down and have it reappear when he/she scrolls back to the very top?

If yes, can anyone show me how or an example?  Very grateful.

> test Content

Comment: This is very possible and many examples can be found online if you research.... 2.4k reputation and you post a question like this? You should know example(s) of your source code & attempts should be included also a detailed description of the specific issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this question has been asked before. check the link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665784/hide-contents-when-page-is-scrolling-down-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is an example on [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vivinantony/onqn2gjj/) It uses JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('.fade').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.fade').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

and CSS:

```
body {
    height: 2000px;    
}
.fade {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #d15757;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This requires `jQuery` which isn't tagged in this question. I think it would be better to ask if using the `jQuery` library is an option before offering a solution like this or clearly explain the use of `jQuery` in your answer and to link to that library.